# Escaping in jquery find

Tags: jquery

I have a id of DOM element in a variable

```
var elm = 'myelement';
```

How can i do

```
$('#myelement a')
```

I just know

```
$('#' + elm) .. how to put anchor tag  here ?
```

Comment: `$('#' + elm + ' a')`?

Comment: k = '#' + elm+ ' a' ; $k

Comment: i've been trying to do .. this.$elm.find('#' + this.sliderOpt.id + 'a').last().prev() , doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @user1184100, you've been given the answers below.  Your comments seems to suggest you didn't read the answers.  What you've written i your comment should look like this: `$('#' + elm).find('a').last().prev();`.

Comment: And if you're going to use that syntax you have to put a space before thea in the selector like this ' a'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add to your concatenation this way -

```
$('#' + elm + ' a')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `find()` function.

```
var elm = $('#myelement');
var anchorElement = elm.find('a');
```

Bear in mind that this will return **all** of the anchor sibling anchor tags. You might want to add an additional class or selector. For example, to only return the first anchor tag, you can use this -

```
var firstAnchorElement = elm.find('a:first');
```

---

If you only want to use one selector then you can create a selector from all the element names you have.

```
var elementId = 'myId';
var childElement = 'a';
var anchorElement = $("#" + elementId + " " + childElement );
```

Although with this method, as you can see - your code starts to become less and less readable.

Comment: I agree, cleaner than mine too. OP should avoid these kind of concatenations if possible.

Comment: Question is basically asking how to concatenate the `var elm` into the jQuery selector, not actually how to walk the DOM. Really, Jay Blanchard's answer (so far) is the only one that answers the question directly and correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

```
$('#' + elm + ' a') // basically is $('#myelement a')
```

Or:

```
$('#' + elm).find('a') // basically is $('#myelement').find('a')
```